# extract repeated elements in a list in python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list comprehension problem which I'd be grateful if someone can solve. The problem goes like this:

I have a list of elements: listX and listY

```
listX = [1,7,7,4,5,7,7]

listY = [2,4,4,3,1,4,6]
```

I want to extract the repeated elements of listX and listY but I need to ensure that (1) There are only **3 pairs** of repeated elements in each of listX and listY and (2) that the indexes of repeated elements are the same for both lists. This means that in listX the repeated element is '7' and for listY the repeated element is '4' and they both share the same indexes of 1,2,5  - Although the repeated element appears in index 6 in listX it doesn't appear as a repeated element in listY therefore it is not counted as a repeated pair.

I want the repeated pairs of elements to be extracted and the lists  listX and listY to be updated with the repeat elements removed.

So the final output would be

```
listX = [1,4,5,7]
listY = [2,3,1,6]
```

with extracted values

```
x=7
y=4
```

from listX and listY respectively

Comment: It would be better if you post your final output and what did you try so far?

Comment: Thanks @IronFist I've clarified my original post. I wasn't sure how to make a proper start because I ran into multiple initial problems like once I 'pop'-ed repeated elements how I would have to update the index of the elements that needed 'pop'ing after the list has been shifted with a repeated element removed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, count how often each pair appears, using `zip` and a dictionary:

```
listX = [1,7,7,4,5,7,7]
listY = [2,4,4,3,1,4,6]

pairs = {}
for (x, y) in zip(listX, listY):
    pairs[(x,y)] = pairs.get((x,y), 0) + 1
```

Or, as suggested in comments, using `collections.Counter`:

```
pairs = collections.Counter(zip(listX, listY))
```

Now, `pairs` will be `{(1, 2): 1, (7, 4): 3, (7, 6): 1, (4, 3): 1, (5, 1): 1}`. You can also use that dictionary to check how many repeated pairs there are, in case you need this, and which pair(s) are repeated the most often, or a certain number of times.
Then, filter those pairs that have the right count and distribute them back to the lists, again using `zip`:

```
listX, listY = zip(*[p for p in zip(listX, listY) if pairs[p] != 3])
```

Now, `listX` and `listY` are `(1, 4, 5, 7)` and `(2, 3, 1, 6)` (those are tuples, but you can easily convert those to lists again).

To get the repeated pair itself, you can do something like this:

```
pair = pairs.most_common(1) # when using collections.Counter
pair = [p for p, c in pairs.items() if c == 3] # otherwise
```

Comment: in such case you can also use `pairs=collections.Counter(zip(listX,listY))` of course :)

Comment: Hi @tobias_k  how would I extract the values of the repeated pairs from this?

Comment: @tobias_k thanks this is exactly what I was looking for.